# How to get unique values with each

Tags: jquery

I want to get values by checkbox data. Everything works, but I do not understand how to make it so that the same values would not be repeated.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.export_phones', function(e) {
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not(:disabled)');
    checkboxes.each(function() {
        var phone = $(this).data('phone');
        $('.phones').append("<br />" + phone);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phones"></div>
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="1481" data-phone="12345678"> ID: 1481 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="1482" data-phone="12345678"> ID: 1482 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="1483" data-phone="987654321"> ID: 1483 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="1484" data-phone="654123"> ID: 1484 <br /><br />
<button class="btn btn-xs export_phones">Export phones</button>
```

Comment: is `checkboxes` array?

Comment: Well it depends on what user experience you want to achive, what I would do, once you add some ID, I would remove that checkbox so it is not available for user to use again (and ability to remove from top - which adds checkbox once again). Or simply clear your $.phones when ever you run add again - or loop to check which is kinda nonsense to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/38f6sa7j/

Explanation:

```
    var phones = []; // make array for phone numbers
...
    if(phones.indexOf(phone) === -1) phones.push(phone); // check if phone number exists already
...
    $('.phones').html(phones.join('<br>')) // join phone numbers with br tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `checkboxes` is `array` You can convert array to `set` in  javascript.

```
var arr = [44,55, 44, 65,65,55];

var set = new Set(arr);

console.log(set)
```